# CSS Selector "If it has this child"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select this div:

```
<div class="k-widget k-window">
```

if it has this child

```
<div id="window_Monthly">
```

I've tried:

```
$("div.k-window:has(div#window_Monthly)")
```

Comment: And did that not work?

Comment: `if($('div.k-window').children('#window_Monthly').length)`

Comment: That works your problem is somewhere else. Check http://jsfiddle.net/r9EP8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/). According to API,

> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").has(selector/DOMElement) instead.

---

However, there are a few other ways you can go about this:

### SELECTORS:

```
$("div.k-window div#window_Monthly")
$(".k-window #window_Monthly")
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/JHQXd/1/

### IF/LENGTH:

IMO, it would be best to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.children()` but both are valid.

```
if($('div.k-window').find('#window_Monthly').length)
     //do something
```

or

```
if($('div.k-window').find('#window_Monthly').length > 0)
         //do something
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/JHQXd/2/

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution works.** Please check this `jsFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/JHQXd/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.k-widget>#window_Monthly').parent()
```

in case the child is not a first-level descendant:

```
$('.k-widget #window_Monthly').parents('.k-widget')
```

Comment: It only works when the children element is the first-level descendant of parent element.

Comment: is that not the requirement?

Comment: The question is not clear but it can be `.k-widget > .whatever > #window_Monthly`.